# Multiple selection from a table

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two tables defined like this. the table location is used to store addresses

```
locations
---------
id
addr
city
zip
name
```

the other table which makes reference to two location address stores in the location table for each entry is this

```
packages
---------
id
client_id
pick_id  <-- this id is for the location address for pick
drop_id  <-- this id is for the location address for drop
```

i want to return

```
location.name, location.addr, location.city, location.id for pick
location.name, location.addr, location.city, location.id for drop
```

both for a given client_id

i currently have this sql

```
Select
  packages.status,
  locations.name,
  locations.address,
  locations.zip,
  locations.city,
  locations.id
From
  packages Inner Join
  locations On packages.drop_id = locations.id And packages.client_id = 5
```

but am getting empty row of result.
can anyone point out my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only appear to be going against the locations table ones, rather for each of the drop and pick locations.

To do both use something like the following:-

```
Select
  packages.status,
  PickLocation.name,
  PickLocation.address,
  PickLocation.zip,
  PickLocation.city,
  PickLocation.id,
  DropLocation.name,
  DropLocation.address,
  DropLocation.zip,
  DropLocation.city,
  DropLocation.id
From packages 
INNER JOIN locations AS PickLocation ON packages.pick_id = PickLocation.id
INNER JOIN locations AS DropLocation ON packages.drop_id = DropLocation.id
WHERE packages.client_id = 5
```

If no records are returned then it suggests client id 5 has no packages, or either the drop or pick up location isn't on the locations table. If the latter then try using LEFT OUTER JOINs rather than INNER JOINs

Comment: You'll most likely need to add aliases for the names, such as `pick_name`, or you'll have two conflicting fields called `name`.

Comment: thank you, i will add the alias myself, let me wait 10mins to accept your answer

Comment: Agreed generally, but no idea what language they are using to access MySQL (so it might be something crude that only supports column numbers).

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't it be :

```
...
ON packages.drop_id = locations.id
WHERE packages.client_id = 5
```

?
Since the packages.client_id is not used by the `JOIN`.

Comment: thanks, but this give me only the drop location, how do i add the pick location?

Comment: This shouldn't really matter with an INNER JOIN (although from a style point of view it does make it more readable to move it out of the ON clause).

Comment: Oh, thank you, I'm sorry I didn't get all your question from the beginning. :)